# How do I set the class for <ul> tag in multilevel submenu in zend_navigation

Tags: zend-framework, zend-navigation

I am using an xml file in creating my navigation in a zend framework app. I have a multilevel menu like so:

```
<config>
<home>
    <label>Home</label>
    <uri>/home</uri>
    <resource>home</resource>
    <id>home</id>
</home>
<register>
    <label>Register</label>
    <uri>/register</uri>
    <resource>register</resource>
    <id>register</id>
</register>
<rates>
    <label>Manage Rates</label>
    <uri>#</uri>
    <resource>managerate</resource>
    <id>managerate</id>
    <pages>
        <charges>
            <label>Transfer Charges</label>
            <uri>/managerates</uri>
        </charges>
        <commission>
            <label>Agent Commission</label>
            <uri>/managerates</uri>
        </commission>
        <exchangerate>
            <label>Exchange Rate</label>
            <uri>/managerates</uri>
        </exchangerate>
    </pages>
</rates>
</config>
```

The  tag renders as a ul tag which wraps around a bunch of li. The overall ul is given a class="navigation". What I want to do is to be able to is assign class attributes to child ul tags, as many levels as the tree goes. Been struggling with this for some time.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220274/need-help-with-zend-navigation-xml/5222129#5222129). It deals with similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I have understood your question correctly:-

To add a class to any menu item, just add it as an element in your xml file. For example to give your `commission` menu item the class 'commission':-

```
<commission>
    <label>Agent Commission</label>
    <uri>/managerates</uri>
    <class>commission</class>
</commission>
```